# Polymer <paper-dialog> selection issue

Tags: polymer

I am having a problem accessing paper-input elements that are inside a paper-dialog. I cant seem to get the value of the paper-input while its inside the paper-dialog, I just get a return value of null. I know there is something like this.$.element but I am confused on how to actually use it. Does the paper-dialog have to be inside a self binding template?

Answer (score 1):

once a paper-dialog is opened it goes into the shadowdom of core-overlay-layer scoping the elements from regular selectors. you can access it's children with the this.$.element syntax if the dialog is inside a auto-binding template

```
<body>
  <template id="app" is="auto-binding">
    // other html content
    <paper-dialog id="dialog">
      <paper-input id="input"></paper-input>
    </paper-dialog>
 </template>
 <script>
   (function () {
     var app = document.querySelector("#app");
     app.addEventListener('template-bound', function () {
       this.getValue = function () {
         return this.$.input.value;
       };
     });
   }());
 </script>
</body>
```

the other option would be to use a auto-binding template like before and create a declarative variable for the input value

```
<body>
  <template id="app" is="auto-binding">
    // other html content
    <paper-dialog id="dialog">
      <paper-input value="{{inputValue}}"></paper-input>
    </paper-dialog>
 </template>
 <script>
   (function () {
     var app = document.querySelector("#app");
     app.addEventListener('template-bound', function () {
       this.getValue = function () {
         return this.inputValue;
       };
     });
   }());
 </script>
</body>
```

a way to get around using the auto-binding template would be to put the dialog in a custom element and enclose all it's functionality there that would allow you to use either of these methods.

i hope this helps.